# String interpolate in mongoose query in order to make it generic

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
qry = User.findOneAndUpdate({username: obj.username}, {$push: {'data.${category}': newBill}});
```

here category is used as pass by reference. It can be anything like Water, electricity, internet etc. The above code gives me syntax error

Comment: Change `'data.${category}'` to `\`data.${category}\``

Comment: sry I am using backticks it gives me syntax error on that